# Pulling an object with a rope

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I have a question with our practical life, see the below question.

[image]

[image]

I tried to pull an object with these two ways but the force I should add was different in the two situations. As the second picture I tied the end of the rope in a tree, and I pulled the rope by the middle point of the rope. As the second time I felt more easy than the first situation. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Sure this isn't relevant? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulley

Comment: Sir, the rope has tied to the tree. Not placed as a pulley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is an effective gearing system created.

Moving the rope sideways the tension increases significantly, redirecting the effort to pull the load. A large sideways deviation creates a small change in tree-load distance, so it is geared.
To take advantage of this, move the rope laterally, re-tie it and repeat.

Without the tree lateral movement of the rope is wasted, and hads to be minimised.

[image]

The gear ratio is

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y}{x}$

which is very small for a straight rope.

Comment: Just checking. You'd be suprised some of the posts.

Comment: Sir can you draw a free body diagram for explain your answer more...